# Custom dynamic item pricing gets reset on Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, checkout, price

I am having a problem getting my price updates to stick. More or less this is a sample of what I am using to update the prices:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'cst_product_quantity_discounter', 10 );
function cst_product_quantity_discounter( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ){
        return;
    }

    if( ! isset( WC()->session->reload_checkout ) ) {

        // declare woocommerce global
        global $woocommerce;      

        // array of ID's to match that represent each item

        $special_ids_array = [
            0 => array( "id" => 15372, "product" => "TAF", "single_bag_price" => 42.99, "3_multiplier" => 0.82181902768 ),
            1 => array( "id" => 14285, "product" => "POW", "single_bag_price" => 29.99, "3_multiplier" => 0.8890741358 )
        ];

        // gather cart object
        $wc_cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

        foreach( $wc_cart as $cart_item ){

            // gather relevant data for testing and comparisons
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
            $product_key = $cart_item['key'];
            $pack_size_attribute = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_pa_sample-check']; // returns: "full-pack" || "sample" || null
            $item_quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

            foreach ( $special_ids_array as $id_test_2 ) {
                if ( $product_id === $id_test_2["id"] && $pack_size_attribute !== "sample" ){
                    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
                        // if the key matches we will set the price of the correct product
                        if ( $key === $product_key ){
                            $discounted_price = 10;
                            $value['data']->set_price($discounted_price);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

There is some other stuff to get the values seen but that works. this will update on my test cart page and everything looks fine.

My issue is when I go to my test checkout page the prices update briefly, then they are overwritten by the original price. I am missing some update thats being run on checkout and `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook does not seem to be making a permanent change on the checkout page.

Where do I need to hook my function so the changes persist whatever loads are occurring on checkout that overwrite the initial successful price change?

Comment: updated with more complete function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some strange things in your code:

- The `$cart_object` (that is the `WC_Cart` object) is already an argument in the hooked function *(it replaces `WC()->cart` or outdated `$woocommerce->cart` )*…
- So `WC()->cart->get_cart()` and `$cart_object->cart_contents` are exactly the same thing. The best is using `$cart_object->get_cart()` in your foreach loops.
- You don't need `global $woocommerce;` as it's already included in `WC()` (the global Woocommerce object so already in `$cart_object`)
- `reload_checkout` doesn't exist in `WC_Sessions` or `WC_Session_Handler` classes *(so your condition is always true)* and anyway this is not useful for this hook.
- For info `$cart_item['data']` is an instance of the `WC_Product` object for this cart item.
- You are have 2 cart loops one in the other and you can make everything in one (it will avoid problems).
- `$cart_item['key']` and the `$key` *(in the cart loop)* are always the same thing. You will not really need to use it in this case…
- You have removed completely the prices calculations in this new edit of your question and the pricing is not dynamic anymore (based on the product quantity like before).

> So I have tried to add back a kind of **dynamic price calculation** *in more real conditions*, but in a different way based on your `$special_ids_array` array keys/values.
>
> The calculated dynamic price discount start with a quantity of 3 by item that match the conditions (Product Ids et "pack size" attribute).

So All this simplifies and compact a lot this revisited code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'custom_product_quantity_discounter', 10, 1 );
function custom_product_quantity_discounter( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // array of ID's to match that represent each item
    $special_ids = array(
        0 => array( "id" => 15372, "product" => "TAF", "single_bag_price" => 42.99, "3_multiplier" => 0.82181902768 ),
        1 => array( "id" => 14285, "product" => "POW", "single_bag_price" => 29.99, "3_multiplier" => 0.8890741358 ),
    );

    // Loop through the cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product_id  = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $quantity    = $cart_item['quantity'];
        $pack_size   = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_pa_sample-check']; // returns "full-pack", "sample" or null
        foreach ( $special_ids as $special_id ){
            if( $special_id['id'] == $product_id && $pack_size !== 'sample' && $quantity >= 3 ){
                $discounted_price = $special_id['single_bag_price'] * $special_id['3_multiplier']; // calculation (fake and custom)
                $cart_item['data']->set_price($discounted_price); // set the calculated price
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.

> The dynamic calculated pricing based on cart item quantities and custom calculation persist in checkout even when reloading the page multiple times.

Comment: Oh my....It seems I was writing some rather redundant jazz. I have tested this and it works great; perhaps mine was just looping all over and breaking things; but this is excellent. thank you for the revision!